# Expressing statements in terms of predicates and quantifiers

Tags: predicate-logic

Given two sets:

A={ Me, Ve, Ea, Ma, Jup, Sat, Ura, Nep} ;

B={Eu, Io, Dei, Fo}.

I need to express the following statements in terms of predicates and quantifiers:

(a) There is a planet that does not orbit the sun;

(b) All planets and their moons orbit the sun;

(C) Not all moons that orbit the sun orbit Mars.

In my textbook there is no similar problem so I don't know how to solve it.

I was thinking that if P(x)is the statement "x orbits the sun", then (a) becomes

```
$\exist x\in A(\neg P(x))$.
```

For (b) I think it is

$\forall x\in A\cup B P(x)$.

Then if Q(x,y) is x orbits y for (c) we have

$(\neg \forall  x\in B)( Q(x, Sun))(Q(x, Mars)).$

Am i right??

Comment: It seems that $A$ is the set of Planets and $B$ is the set of Moons. You have to use them as "predicates" ?

Comment: Yes, perhaps. I don't know. I thought if P(x, y) is the statement x orbits y, then

Comment: If so, we can express (a) $\exists x \in A (\lnot P(x,\text {Sun}))$.

Comment: I think we can't use Sun as variable. Maybe if P(x) is the statement x orbits the Sun, then (a) is \exists x\in A: \neg P(x)?